# Counter example to show that S does not form a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a problem that asks me to give a counterexample or prove that it is closed under addition/multiplication depending on if it forms a subspace or not.

$$S = \begin{bmatrix} |a-b|\\ |b-c| \\ a+b+c\end{bmatrix}$$

where S is the set of all vectors in R^3, a,b,c, in Real Numbers

a = 0, b = 0, c = 0 and results are 0 which is a real number so it contains the zero vector.

a = 1, b = 2, c = 3 results in 1, 1, 6 which are real numbers and a = 2, b = 1, c = 3 results in 1, 2, 6 which are real numbers and their sum a = 3, b =3, c = 6 results in 0, 0, 12 which are real numbers which means its closed under addition.

a = 1, b = 2, c = 3 results in 1, 1, 6 and you have an arbitrary constant, lets say 2, which gives a = 2, b = 4, c = 6. This results in 2, 2, 12 which are real numbers which means its closed under multiplication.

However, the answer given was that it was not a subspace. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Improve your question, the first statement is not clear. [ |a-b|

|b-c|

a + b + c ]??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> a = 1, b = 2, c = 3 results in 1, 1, 6 and you have an **arbitrary constant, lets say 2**, which gives a = 2, b = 4, c = 6. This results in 2, 2, 12 which are real numbers which means its closed under multiplication.

You say *arbitrary* but then you pick $2$; this doesn't prove it always works...!

**Hint**: the first two components are absolute values and thus non-negative. What about taking a negative scalar multiple, e.g. $-2$ instead of $2$? You found that $(1,1,6) \in S$, what about:
$$-2 \cdot (1,1,6) = (-2,-2,-12)$$

Comment: Since -2, is negative and it's supposed to be non-negative, (-2,-2,-12) is not in the S and thus not closed under multiplication right? And as a result, it does not form a subspace. So I'm supposed to check if the result of a,b, and c are closed under addition/multiplication and not the values a,b, and c themselves?

Comment: I don't think you completely got what it is that you have to check. Closed under scalar multiplication means that _if_ a vector is in $S$, then _all_ its scalar multiples should also be in $S$. Now you found that $(1,1,6)$ is in $S$ and my suggestion is that you think about its negative scalar multiples - are they in $S$; why or why not?